# Is it possible to bind a DataGridCheckBoxColumn to Nullable<DateTime>.HasValue?

Tags: wpf, binding, entity-framework-4, datagrid, checkbox

I have this column in the database

```
enddate DATETIME NULL
```

Entity Framework translated it to

```
DateTime? ENDDATE
```

I have a column in my DataGrid

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn
      Binding="{Binding Path=ENDDATE.HasValue}"
      Header="Concluded?" />
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, but are you sure you'd use `Binding=…`? I'd expect it to be something like `IsChecked="{Binding Path=ENDDATE.HasValue}"`.

Comment: When I use IsChecked="{Binding Path=ENDDATE}" it checks the cells where it is null.

Comment: @Jay probably not, since it doesn't work

Comment: Does EndDate raise a notification?  Does it raise one when if you do EndDate.Value = ...  Can you try adding a specific property EndDateHasValue{get{}} and raise a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using Mvvm Light:

```
public class DataItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private double? _number;
    public double? Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            Set(()=>Number, ref _number, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>NumberHasValue);
        }
    }

    public bool NumberHasValue
    {
        get { return Number.HasValue; }
    }
}

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding NumberHasValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```